# FragmentPagerAdapter's Fragment not showing RecyclerView's items

Tags: android, android-fragments

I think the easiest way to show the problem is the gif below. When i'm on the home fragment, and switch to Recent, Recent is a fragment with ViewPager and TabLayout, the item that's supposed to be in the recyclerView shows up normally, but when i go back to Home Fragment, and go back to Recent, the Item is not there anymore. I believe that it has something to do with the fact that when I go back to the Recent Fragment, even though the Recent Fragment's `onCreate()` is being called, the 'All' Fragment, which is the first in the ViewPager is not calling it's `onCreate()`.

It's calling the `onResume()` however, and i check the RecyclerView's list size in there, and it still has the item in it, it just not showing up.

How can i fix that?

Is there a way to force the `FragmentPagerAdapter` to call `onCreate()` on it's fragment's, like the 'All' Fragment when going back?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, didn't know where to even look for the problem so i didn't post the code in question to not make it too long.

When using a `ViewPager` inside a `Fragment`, don't use `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` when creating `FragmentPagerAdapter`, use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead.

So when it comes to code, use this:

```
MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager());
```

Instead of :

```
MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
```